# NetSuite Tax Rate not showing

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

So I was doing a simple custom search but somehow the tax rate is not showing. I am still new to NetSuite and I tried to find workarounds about this. Any suggestions?

```
     var columns = new Array();
    columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
    columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('name');
    columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('itemid');
    columns[3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('rate');
    columns[4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('taxtype')

    var res = nlapiSearchRecord('salesTaxItem', null, null, columns);
    wcache('res---> '+ JSON.stringify(res));
    return;
```

Comment: What record type are you searching?

Comment: To be honest I am still wandering around but I am looking for records that contains a list of tax codes and tax rates. And according to a guide I read I can find them at salestaxitem

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it matters but the name should be 'salestaxitem' not 'salesTaxItem' Also do you know if you have any tax items or codes in your account?

If you are on a One World account you need to make sure you have access to the subisdiary that has tax items.

Comment: There are tax items/codes here but for some reason only "rate" returns me a null result. 

Also I am encountering this problem using a sandbox account. I'll try to research about subsidiaries on my admin account and try this solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I see all the rates when I run your code in my account.

The Netsuite record browser has this to say about the rate field:

> Enter the appropriate tax rate as a percentage. Example: 8% This percentage will be calculated when you select this tax item on transactions. This field is available only if the SuiteTax feature is disabled in your account.

Comment: Thank you for testing it but I still I am sure that the tax codes are properly coded. I just checked them earlier but then again it still doesn't work. I guess I'll try sending a ticket for now. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Check whether SuiteTax is enabled in your account

Comment: Everything is now working fine. I tried to remake my code using suitescript 2.0 and it immediately fix my problems. Thank you for your advice!